# Unwind and remove duplicates based on string comparison

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb (version 2.6) document like this:

```
{
    "Uniprot": {
        "GO": [
            "cytoplasm [GO:0005737]",
            "nucleolus [GO:0005730]",
            "calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]",
            "zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]"
        ],
        "GO cc": [
            "cytoplasm [GO:0005737]",
            "nucleolus [GO:0005730]"
        ],
        "GO bp": [
            ""
        ],
        "GO mf": [
            "calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]",
            "zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]"
        ],
        "GO_ID": [
            "GO:0005509",
            "GO:0005737",
            "GO:0005730",
            "GO:0008270"
        ]
    }
}
```

With the following code, where test_3 is the collection with the previous document is:

```
project = {"$project":{"_id": False,
               "Uniprot": "$Uniprot.Uniprot",
               "GO Description": {
                    "$cond":[
                    {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO cc"]},
                    "$Uniprot.GO cc",
                        {"$cond":[
                        {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO mf"]},
                        "$Uniprot.GO mf",
                            {"$cond":[
                            {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO bp"]},
                            "$Uniprot.GO bp", False]}]}]},
               "GO Type": {"$cond":[
                    {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO cc"]},
                    "Cellular component",
                        {"$cond":[
                        {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO mf"]},
                        "Molecular function",
                            {"$cond":[
                            {"$eq": ["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO bp"]},
                            "Biological Process", False]}]}]},
               "GO ID":"$Uniprot.GO_ID"}}
redact = {"$redact":{"$cond":[{"$or":[
                            {"$eq":["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO cc"]},
                            {"$eq":["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO mf"]},
                            {"$eq":["$Uniprot.GO", "$Uniprot.GO bp"]}]},
                                            "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE"]}}
d = test_3.aggregate([{"$match":{"Uniprot.Uniprot": "P33764"}},
                      {"$unwind":"$Uniprot.GO"},
                      {"$unwind":"$Uniprot.GO cc"},
                      {"$unwind":"$Uniprot.GO bp"},
                      {"$unwind":"$Uniprot.GO mf"},
                      redact,
                      {"$unwind":"$Uniprot.GO_ID"},
                      project
                      ])
```

The output is:

```
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm [GO:0005737]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus [GO:0005730]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding [GO:0005509]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding [GO:0008270]', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
```

Now I modify the output using:

```
b = []
for i in d:
    go = i["GO Description"][-13:]
    if i["GO ID"] == go[2:-1]:
        entry = i.copy()
        entry["GO Description"] = i["GO Description"][:-13]
        if entry not in b:
            b.append(entry)
for i in b:
    print i
```

To obtain my expected output:

```
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005737', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'cytoplasm', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005730', u'GO Type': u'Cellular component', u'GO Description': u'nucleolus', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0005509', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'calcium ion binding', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
{u'GO ID': u'GO:0008270', u'GO Type': u'Molecular function', u'GO Description': u'zinc ion binding', u'Uniprot': u'P33764'}
```

However, this way it is slow, and I want to do it in mongodb without further processing in python. How can I do it?
Things I noted: the  aggregation produce duplicate lines due to the unwind of GO and GO_ID (Thats why there is the `if entry not in b`) and I need to check if `GO ID` is on the `GO Description`, because I couldn't find a way to do it with `$search` or with `$text`.

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: Whenever such question are asked . Expected output, will help you getting your answer fastly ..

Comment: @chridam csharpcoder I edited the question.